# How to perform Intersection with custom property in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Random:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id=id
        self.prop=None

list_1={Random(12), Random(15), Random(22)}
list_2={Random(22),Random(9),Random(88)}
list_3={Random(88),Random(22),Random(12)}

result=list_1.intersection(list_2).intersection(list_3)
print (list(result))

#expected result = Random Object containing id=22
#returned result =[]
```

How to custom intersect among lists with custom field - id in the above case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) says:

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.

And `hashable` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-hashable) says:

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.

So you need to implement `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` for your class.

```
class Random:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id=id
        self.prop=None

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.id, self.prop))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id and self.prop == other.prop
```

Comment: do I have control over which object to return?

Comment: Return what object from where?

Comment: comparing left with right based on the id but only select the object where the prop ='red' and not the other object which has prop='green'

Comment: You can implement `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` in any way that makes sense for your code. But if you compare only by `id` and not `prop` that means that two objects with the same `id` and different `prop` will be considered equal. If that makes sense for your case, nothing stops you from doing that.

Comment: i want to comapre id but since its intersection i want only the object containing prop=red to be returned . how and where do i make that selection ? or do i have to do it separetly

Comment: You can just get `prop` from the return object. If you want a list of just that, you can use something like `[i.prop for i in result]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Random:
    def __new__(cls, id):
        return id


list_1 = {Random(12), Random(15), Random(22)}
list_2 = {Random(22), Random(9), Random(88)}
list_3 = {Random(88), Random(22), Random(12)}

result = list_1.intersection(list_2).intersection(list_3)
print(list(result))
```

if you need id then u can try new of class method because it returns a value.
without return u got the object of a class that is all different that's why your result is empty